# Apsotrophe for plural possessive noun. E.g. Company Name

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Consider the following exemplary company names:

> - Texas Coffee Grounders
> - Mighty Chicken Wings
> - Super Pooper Scoopers

Should one reference the possessive form of any of the above company names, where should the apostrophe be placed?

E.g.

> Texas Coffee **Grounders's** head office is based in Houston.

...or...

> Texas Coffee **Grounders'** head office is based in Houston.

Comment: I would say the second example was correct.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks Edwin but my concern with the referenced question is that it lacked specificity to company name nouns ending with a pluralised word. I.e. A proper noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Understood. Rectified by marking as duplicate. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grounders' - Because you don't say 'Grounderses' when you read it out aloud.  Refer to *The Penguin Guide to Punctuation* by RL Trask. Chapter on the apostrophe (don't worry it's only a small chapter) http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe

Comment: You're assuming that the 'pronunciation governs correct form of punctuating' rule is universally accepted. It's not. Though it's admittedly pretty commonly adopted. //  But this has been covered before on ELU.